# Songplay (no.1)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, music

This took a while to write so I hope everyone enjoys it! The idea is for you to figure out what song it is and who it’s by. Good luck to you all!

---

### The Rules

- The riddle has to match the original rhymes.
- The riddle has to stay with the original flow of the section you choose.
- You must explain what the song is about as best you can.
- Subtly giving away the artist or title is fine.

### The Puzzle

> Trial
>
> Don’t understand
>
> I filled his mind with lead
>
> Now I’m chained here to this bed
>
> Fire
>
> His life is now undone
>
> And now I’ve got to go ahead and pray

Comment: Love this, please make more! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is

> “Bohemian Rhapsody” by Queen 
>  This follows the meter and rhyme of:
>  Mama 
> just killed a man
>  Put a gun against his head
>  Pulled my trigger, now he's dead
>  Mama 
>  life had just begun
>  But now I've gone and thrown it all away